# Why can't my loop detect \0 symbol in const string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, char

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Mystring {
    char *arr;
public:
    Mystring(const char pointer[]) {
        int i = 0;
        while (pointer[i] != '\0') {
            i++;
            cout << pointer[i] << endl;
        }
        arr = new char[i];
        i = 0;
        while (pointer[i] != '\0') {
            arr[i] = pointer[i];
            i++;
        }
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Mystring& str) {
        int i = 0;
        while (str.arr[i] != '\0') {
            out << str.arr[i];
            i++;
        }
        return out;
    }
};

int main() {
    Mystring string("Hello, world!");
    cout << string << endl;
}
```

I'm trying to create my own string class. The length of "hello world!" is 13, but the length of arr turns out to be 17. It is filled with some strange chars for some reason I don't understand. When I'm trying to cout string it returns this: Hello, world!¤¤¤¤.

Comment: It must not be your problem, but note that using `string` as a variable name, in addition to `using namespace std;`, is confusing at least.

Comment: And note that you don't add `\0` in your `str.arr[.];`

Comment: I thought compiler automatically does it

Comment: It helped actually. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add `'\0'` at the end of your `arr[]`.

Moreover, the size or `arr`should be increased to incorporate this `\0`, as noted in @user7860670's answer.

Moreover, using `string` as a variable name, in addition to `using namespace std;`, is confusing at least.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm>

//using namespace std;

class Mystring {
    char *arr;
public:
    Mystring(const char pointer[]) {
        int i = 0;
        while (pointer[i] != '\0') {
            i++;
            std::cout << pointer[i] << std::endl;
        }
        arr = new char[i+1];
        i = 0;
        while (pointer[i] != '\0') {
            arr[i] = pointer[i];
            i++;
        }
        arr[i] = '\0';
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Mystring& str) {
        int i = 0;
        while (str.arr[i] != '\0') {
            out << str.arr[i];
            i++;
        }
        return out;
    }
};

int main() {
    Mystring mstring("Hello, world!");
    std::cout << mstring << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Buffer size required to hold `"Hello, world!"` (including terminating null) is 14 while you only allocate space for 13 chars and completely omit terminating null. So during iteration inside of `operator<<` buffer index will go out of bounds which is Undefined Behavior.

You should allocate one extra byte and make sure that buffer ends with terminating null

```
arr = new char[i + 1];
i = 0;
while (pointer[i] != '\0')
{
   arr[i] = pointer[i];
   ++i;
}
arr[i] = '\0';
```